# Consume django data in nextjs

Tags: javascript, django, api, rest, next.js

I struggle to consume rest API data with NextJs.

In particular, I don't understand how to fetch the end points.

My need is to loop through the data, but

using posts.map, raises error data.map is not a function
which is logical as my API describes an object and not a list.

But then if I call only {data.id} the result is a blank page. I.e. without the mapping.

What am I missing here?
If possible, I'd like to convert the object into a list so I can loop and call it by the props, but how?
Any input would be highly appreciated.

API:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "total_count": 3
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "meta": {
                "type": "home.HomePage",
                "detail_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v2/pages/3/",
                "html_url": "http://localhost:8000/",
            },
            "title": "Home"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "meta": {
                "type": "news.NewsPage",
                "detail_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v2/pages/4/",
                "html_url": "http://localhost:8000/breaking-news/",
            },
            "title": "Breaking news"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "meta": {
                "type": "blog.BlogPage",
                "detail_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v2/pages/5/",
                "html_url": "http://localhost:8000/blog-api/",
            },
            "title": "blog api"
        }
    ]
}
```

Index.js

```js
import Link from "next/link"

//getStaticProps 
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const API_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/pages/"
  const request = await fetch(API_URL)
  const data = await request.json()
  return{
    props:{
        data
    },
  }
}

//route 
export default function Game({ data }) {
  return (
    <div>
   {data.map((card, key) => (
   <div>
       <p>{card.title}</p>
       <p>{card.id}</p>...   </div>
   ))}
</div> 
  )


* When I replace the data.map bloc with a {data.id} or data.title, the rendered page is empty. 
return (
    <div>      
       <p>{card.title}</p>
       <p>{card.id}</p>    
</div>
```

Comment: in `getStaticProps` if you `console.log(data)` what do u get?

Comment: If I place the console.log(data) just after the getStaticProps block, it states: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: You have to post django api code. How you are returning data.